# ODATA ODATA The query specified in the URI is not valid: top=100&$orderby=tolower(fieldName)%20asc

Tags: c#, odata

I am getting below error whilst using toLower on the field that I would like to order, looks like expressions are not supported on order by .

Example :top=100&$orderby=tolower(fieldName)%20asc

Error:

ODATA The query specified in the URI is not valid. Only ordering by properties is supported for non-primitive collections. Expressions are not supported

Answer (score 0):

I think that depends on the backend that is handling the query. A similar query to the TripPin service works without an error:

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People?$orderby=tolower(FirstName) desc,UserName
```